# How can optimize the query with join

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query large query which is taking more time to execute.How can i reduce the execution time of the query using Join.Here is myt query.

```
SELECT mdi.Member_Id,
dp.Payment1_Date AS Duchess_Payment1_Date,
dp.Payment1_Method AS Duchess_Payment1_Method,
dp.Payment1_By AS Duchess_Payment1_By,
dp.Payment1_Amount AS Duchess_Payment1_Amount,
dp.Payment2_Date AS Duchess_Payment2_Date,
dp.Payment2_Method AS Duchess_Payment2_Method,
dp.Payment2_By AS Duchess_Payment2_By,
dp.Payment2_Amount AS Duchess_Payment2_Amount,
mha.First_Name AS Member_First_Name,
mha.Middle_Name AS Member_Middle_Name,
mha.Last_Name AS Member_Last_Name,
mha.Address AS Member_Address,
mha.City AS Member_City,
mha.State AS Member_State,
mha.Zip AS Member_Zip,
mha.Nickname AS Member_Nickname,
mha.Phone AS Member_Phone,
mha.Mobile AS Member_Mobile,
mha.Email AS Member_Email,
mwa.First_Name AS Work_First_Name,
mwa.Middle_Name AS Work_Middle_Name,
mwa.Last_Name AS Work_Last_Name,
mwa.Address AS Work_Adrress,
mwa.City AS Work_City,
mwa.State AS Work_State,
mwa.Zip AS Work_Zip,
mwa.Phone AS Work_Phone,
(CASE WHEN mha.Preferred=0 THEN 'Work Address' WHEN mha.Preferred=1 THEN 'Home Address' END)AS Preferred,
mmt.Admiral_Title,
mmt.Spouse_Title,
mmt.Couple_Title,
mdi.Year AS Duchess_Year,
mdi.College AS Duchess_College,
mdi.Major AS Duchess_Major,
mdi.Sorority AS Duchess_Sorority,
mdi.Parent_Name AS Duchess_Parent_Name,
mdi.Escort_Name AS Duchess_Escort_Name
FROM duchess_payment dp
JOIN  member_duchess_info mdi ON mdi.Duchess_Id = dp.Duchess_Id 
JOIN  member_home_address mha ON mha.Member_Id = mdi.Member_Id
JOIN  member_work_address mwa ON mwa.Member_Id = mdi.Member_Id
JOIN  member_mailing_title mmt ON mmt.Member_Id = mdi.Member_Id
ORDER BY dp.Duchess_Id;
```

this is the way Iam using . Is it corrct?.
when i try to executing that query it is still taking more time.

here is the explain of the query

[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: Please post the results of EXPLAIN {your query}

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` on your query to get some information to work with..

Comment: Make sure all the Member_Id and Duchess_Id fields are indexed.

Comment: @Jaydee Iam very new to this.Can explain me some more brief.

Comment: Your query seems to be well structured and the use of jointures is correct. The important point is now the indexes of you different tables in order to improve the query performance

Comment: In the MySQL shell or Workbench or other database tool, re-run your query, but put the word EXPLAIN in front of it.

Comment: @Jaydee You will find the explain info in the question

Answer (score 1):

Use indexes on the items on which you are performing joins e.g Duchess_Id, Member_Id etc

Comment: How to use indexing for that query.

Comment: ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD INDEX <column_name> ..  refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html for deep info